# with adb, set "allow messages" to "from anyone" while in do not disturb mode

Tags: android, adb, android-settings

I would like to be able to toggle the "allow messages" while in do not disturb mode from adb. I haven't found the related parameters in settings (either system, global or secure), even though I found how to toggle "do not disturb" using zen mode.

The setting can be found in parameters/Apps and notifications/Notifications/Do not disturb/See all exceptions. The phone I'm using is on Android 10.

[image]

Please note that the final use case is to be able to do it from a script run on a computer.

Thanks in advance for your help.